# Different text color for each class object?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm making some kind of "game score tracker". Here's how the app currently works:

1. User adds players by typing a name into EditText and then clicking ok button.
2. After the user finished adding new players, he presses "start game" button and a new activity opens.
3. Players are added to Parcelable extra and taken to the next activity.
4. In the next activity, a user has a spinner, EditText and +, - buttons. After the user selects a certain player from the spinner, types in a certain score and then either a + or -, a new TextView will appear containing Player name and score.

Example: If there are 3 Players "James, John and Robert". The user then adds 5 points to James, 10 points to John and 15 points to Robert. This is how TextViews will look like:

> James 5
>
> John 10
>
> Robert 15

Then if user will do the exactly same thing again, this will happen:

> James 5
>
> John 10
>
> Robert 15
>
> James 10
>
> John 20
>
> Robert 30

So as you can see, I don't keep the same TextView for each player but I keep adding them (I do want that, I want the user to be able to see his actions, when he clicked - and when +. But is there a way to somehow set a color for each user? Example: James will be blue, John will be red and Robert will be green. How do I pre-determine the color of each Player's TextView?

Player class:

```
public static class Player implements Parcelable{
    String name;
    int score;
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(score);
        dest.writeString(name);
    }

    public Player(Parcel source){
        score = source.readInt();
        name = source.readString();
    }

    public Player(){
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Player> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Novaigra.Player>() {

        @Override
        public Player createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Player(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Player[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Player[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Can I add some kind of color palette to the activity when players are being added so that a user can pre-determine a color or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a color picker, android doesnt have one built in, feel free to modify it to your needs

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.LinearGradient;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class ColorPickerDialog extends Dialog {

public interface OnColorChangedListener {
    void colorChanged(String key, int color);
}

private OnColorChangedListener mListener;
private int mInitialColor, mDefaultColor;
private String mKey;

private class ColorPickerView extends View {
    private Paint mPaint;
    private float mCurrentHue = 0;
    private int mCurrentX = 0, mCurrentY = 0;
    private int mCurrentColor, mDefaultColor;
    private final int[] mHueBarColors = new int[258];
    private int[] mMainColors = new int[65536];
    private OnColorChangedListener mListener;
    private int width,height;

    ColorPickerView(Context c, OnColorChangedListener l, int color,
            int defaultColor) {
        super(c);
        mListener = l;
        mDefaultColor = defaultColor;

        // Get the current hue from the current color and update the main
        // color field
        float[] hsv = new float[3];
        Color.colorToHSV(color, hsv);
        mCurrentHue = hsv[0];
        updateMainColors();

        mCurrentColor = color;

        // Initialize the colors of the hue slider bar
        int index = 0;
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) // Red (#f00) to pink
                                                    // (#f0f)
        {
            mHueBarColors[index] = Color.rgb(255, 0, (int) i);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) // Pink (#f0f) to blue
                                                    // (#00f)
        {
            mHueBarColors[index] = Color.rgb(255 - (int) i, 0, 255);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) // Blue (#00f) to light
                                                    // blue (#0ff)
        {
            mHueBarColors[index] = Color.rgb(0, (int) i, 255);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) // Light blue (#0ff) to
                                                    // green (#0f0)
        {
            mHueBarColors[index] = Color.rgb(0, 255, 255 - (int) i);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) // Green (#0f0) to yellow
                                                    // (#ff0)
        {
            mHueBarColors[index] = Color.rgb((int) i, 255, 0);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) // Yellow (#ff0) to red
                                                    // (#f00)
        {
            mHueBarColors[index] = Color.rgb(255, 255 - (int) i, 0);
            index++;
        }

        // Initializes the Paint that will draw the View
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        mPaint.setTextSize(12);
    }

    // Get the current selected color from the hue bar
    private int getCurrentMainColor() {
        int translatedHue = 255 - (int) (mCurrentHue * 255 / 360);
        int index = 0;
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) {
            if (index == translatedHue)
                return Color.rgb(255, 0, (int) i);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) {
            if (index == translatedHue)
                return Color.rgb(255 - (int) i, 0, 255);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) {
            if (index == translatedHue)
                return Color.rgb(0, (int) i, 255);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) {
            if (index == translatedHue)
                return Color.rgb(0, 255, 255 - (int) i);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) {
            if (index == translatedHue)
                return Color.rgb((int) i, 255, 0);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) {
            if (index == translatedHue)
                return Color.rgb(255, 255 - (int) i, 0);
            index++;
        }
        return Color.RED;
    }

    // Update the main field colors depending on the current selected hue
    private void updateMainColors() {
        int mainColor = getCurrentMainColor();
        int index = 0;
        int[] topColors = new int[256];
        for (int y = 0; y < 256; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++) {
                if (y == 0) {
                    mMainColors[index] = Color.rgb(
                            255 - (255 - Color.red(mainColor)) * x / 255,
                            255 - (255 - Color.green(mainColor)) * x / 255,
                            255 - (255 - Color.blue(mainColor)) * x / 255);
                    topColors[x] = mMainColors[index];
                } else
                    mMainColors[index] = Color.rgb(
                            (255 - y) * Color.red(topColors[x]) / 255,
                            (255 - y) * Color.green(topColors[x]) / 255,
                            (255 - y) * Color.blue(topColors[x]) / 255);
                index++;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int translatedHue = 255 - (int) (mCurrentHue * 255 / 360);
        // Display all the colors of the hue bar with lines
        for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++) {
            // If this is not the current selected hue, display the actual
            // color
            if (translatedHue != x) {
                mPaint.setColor(mHueBarColors[x]);
                mPaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
            } else // else display a slightly larger black line
            {
                mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
            }
            canvas.drawLine(x + 10, 0, x + 10, 40, mPaint);
            // canvas.drawLine(0, x+10, 40, x+10, mPaint);
            //canvas.drawLine(x + width/27, 0, x + width/27,height/8 , mPaint);
        }

        // Display the main field colors using LinearGradient
        for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++) {
            int[] colors = new int[2];
            colors[0] = mMainColors[x];
            colors[1] = Color.BLACK;
            Shader shader = new LinearGradient(0, 50, 0, 306, colors, null,
                    Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);//0,50,0,306
            mPaint.setShader(shader);
            canvas.drawLine(x + 10, 50, x + 10, 306, mPaint);
            //canvas.drawLine(x + width/27, height/8 + 10, x + width/27, height*(5/6), mPaint);
        }
        mPaint.setShader(null);

        // Display the circle around the currently selected color in the
        // main field
        if (mCurrentX != 0 && mCurrentY != 0) {
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            canvas.drawCircle(mCurrentX, mCurrentY, 10, mPaint);
        }

        // Draw a 'button' with the currently selected color
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaint.setColor(mCurrentColor);
        //canvas.drawRect(10, 316, 138, 356, mPaint);
        //canvas.drawRect(width/27, height*(5/6), width/2, height, mPaint);

        // Set the text color according to the brightness of the color
        if (Color.red(mCurrentColor) + Color.green(mCurrentColor)
                + Color.blue(mCurrentColor) < 384)
            mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        else
            mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
       // canvas.drawText(
               // "New Color", 74,
                //340, mPaint);

        // Draw a 'button' with the default color
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaint.setColor(mDefaultColor);
        //canvas.drawRect(138, 316, 266, 356, mPaint);
        //canvas.drawRect(width/2, height*(5/6), width, height, mPaint);

        // Set the text color according to the brightness of the color
        if (Color.red(mDefaultColor) + Color.green(mDefaultColor)
                + Color.blue(mDefaultColor) < 384)
            mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        else
            mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        //canvas.drawText(
              //  "Default Color", 202, 340,
                //mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(276,366 );//276,366
        width = widthMeasureSpec;
        height = heightMeasureSpec;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            return true;
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        // If the touch event is located in the hue bar
        if (x > 10 && x < 266 && y > 0 && y < 40) {
            // Update the main field colors
            mCurrentHue = (255 - x) * 360 / 255;
            updateMainColors();

            // Update the current selected color
            int transX = mCurrentX - 10;
            int transY = mCurrentY - 60;
            int index = 256 * (transY - 1) + transX;
            if (index > 0 && index < mMainColors.length)
                mCurrentColor = mMainColors[256 * (transY - 1) + transX];

            // Force the redraw of the dialog
            invalidate();
        }

        // If the touch event is located in the main field
        if (x > 10 && x < 266 && y > 50 && y < 306) {
            mCurrentX = (int) x;
            mCurrentY = (int) y;
            int transX = mCurrentX - 10;
            int transY = mCurrentY - 60;
            int index = 256 * (transY - 1) + transX;
            if (index > 0 && index < mMainColors.length) {
                // Update the current color
                mCurrentColor = mMainColors[index];
                mListener.colorChanged("", mCurrentColor);
                // Force the redraw of the dialog
                invalidate();
            }
        }

        // If the touch event is located in the left button, notify the
        // listener with the current color
        //if (x > 10 && x < 138 && y > 316 && y < 356)
          //  mListener.colorChanged("", mCurrentColor);

        // If the touch event is located in the right button, notify the
        // listener with the default color
        //if (x > 138 && x < 266 && y > 316 && y < 356)
          //  mListener.colorChanged("", mDefaultColor);

        return true;
    }
}

public ColorPickerDialog(Context context, OnColorChangedListener listener,
        String key, int initialColor, int defaultColor) {
    super(context);

    mListener = listener;
    mKey = key;
    mInitialColor = initialColor;
    mDefaultColor = defaultColor;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    OnColorChangedListener l = new OnColorChangedListener() {
        public void colorChanged(String key, int color) {
            mListener.colorChanged(mKey, color);
            dismiss();
        }
    };

    setContentView(new ColorPickerView(getContext(), l, mInitialColor,
            mDefaultColor));
    setTitle("Pick Text Color");

    }
}
```

then when you get the int color from the colorchangelistener when they pick or if it uses the default or whatever save the int into the player

EDIT: i think i stripped the default out of this one because it doesnt scale too well across devices, something i cant remember, you might wana go through it and check, it works though
you need a button or something to trigger the color picker

in your activity

```
import "your package name".ColorPickerDialog
```

then make your activity

```
implement OnColorChangeListener
```

then in the button for the color picker to come up

```
ColorPickerDialog color = new ColorPickerDialog(this,this, "picker",Color.BLACK,Color.WHITE);
        color.show();
```

the method you should be able to override because you implemented OnColorChangeListener is

```
@Override
public void colorChanged(String key, int color) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    paint.setColor(color);
}
```

i just have paint.setColor() in there but you can save the int color witch is the color selected in the color picker to your Player class and use it for the text color in your textviews.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but could you add any info on how to use this? I'm new to android programming so it's hard implementing something new without a tutorial. I made a new class file and copied this into it so far.

Comment: there i put it in an edit assuming that you know how to make a button or whatever

Answer (score 0):

You can show a color picker dialog to let the user choose a color. Color picker dialog and example of how to use it can be found here: https://github.com/chiralcode/Android-Color-Picker/