# Understanding color picker dialog

Tags: android, colors, shared-libraries

I want to use this color pikcerdialog https://code.google.com/p/android-color-picker/ but i have no idea what to do. I've added external jars and stuff before but this is different when you download it you get a project. I'm not to new to android but am still relatively new. Is that whole project the library or something. I really don't know where to begin but would really like help. even a link to a tutorial would be nice because i dont know what to search.

```
   package com.example.color;

    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
     import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
    import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
    import android.text.Html;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.ImageView;
     import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

 public class AboutDialog extends AlertDialog {

private ImageView                       mIconView;
private TextView                        mAppNameText;
private TextView                        mAboutText;
private TextView                        mVersionText;


public AboutDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);

        mAboutText = (TextView) layout.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
        mVersionText = (TextView) layout.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        mAppNameText = (TextView) layout.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        mIconView = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(android.R.id.icon);

        setView(layout);

        loadAbout();

        setTitle("About");



        mIconView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                int mClickCount = 0;

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        mClickCount++;

                        if(mClickCount == 5) {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Upgraded to Pro Version!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                                SharedPreferences.Editor edit = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext()).edit();                                                     
                                                edit.putBoolean("is_pro", true);
                                                edit.commit();
                                        }

                                }).start();


                        }

                }
        });



        setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, getContext().getString(android.R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                }
        });

}

private void loadAbout(){

        PackageInfo pi = null;
        try {
                pi = getContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getContext().getPackageName(), 0);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mAppNameText.setText("ColorPickerView");        
        mVersionText.setText("Version" + " " + (pi != null ? pi.versionName : "null"));

        String s = "<b>Developed By:</b><br>Daniel Nilsson<br>";                
        mAboutText.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));

 }

}
```

That was the dialog and this is just a really simple activity where i call it from

```
package com.example.color;

  import com.example.color.ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener;

    import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
     import android.view.Menu;
     import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
      import android.widget.Button;

        public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnColorChangedListener,                OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


     Button b =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
  b.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void colorChanged(String key, int color) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   // Paint l = Paint.setColor(color);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ColorPickerDialog color = new ColorPickerDialog(this,this, "picker",Color.BLACK,Color.WHITE);
    color.show();
}
```

}

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552290/different-text-color-for-each-class-object/18552365#18552365

Comment: I followed that and when i run it it says unable to initaite. no empty constructer. Do you know what that would be

Comment: can you put up your code?

Comment: it was a manifest mistake i figured it out. Thank you very much

Comment: not a problem, glad you got it figured out :)

Answer (score 8):

your welcome to use this modify it to your needs

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.LinearGradient;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class ColorPickerDialog extends Dialog {

public interface OnColorChangedListener {
    void colorChanged(String key, int color);
}

private OnColorChangedListener mListener;
private int mInitialColor, mDefaultColor;
private String mKey;

private class ColorPickerView extends View {
    private Paint mPaint;
    private float mCurrentHue = 0;
    private int mCurrentX = 0, mCurrentY = 0;
    private int mCurrentColor, mDefaultColor;
    private final int[] mHueBarColors = new int[258];
    private int[] mMainColors = new int[65536];
    private OnColorChangedListener mListener;
    private int width,height;

    ColorPickerView(Context c, OnColorChangedListener l, int color,
            int defaultColor) {
        super(c);
        mListener = l;
        mDefaultColor = defaultColor;

        // Get the current hue from the current color and update the main
        // color field
        float[] hsv = new float[3];
        Color.colorToHSV(color, hsv);
        mCurrentHue = hsv[0];
        updateMainColors();

        mCurrentColor = color;

        // Initialize the colors of the hue slider bar
        int index = 0;
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) // Red (#f00) to pink
                                                    // (#f0f)
        {
            mHueBarColors[index] = Color.rgb(255, 0, (int) i);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) // Pink (#f0f) to blue
                                                    // (#00f)
        {
            mHueBarColors[index] = Color.rgb(255 - (int) i, 0, 255);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) // Blue (#00f) to light
                                                    // blue (#0ff)
        {
            mHueBarColors[index] = Color.rgb(0, (int) i, 255);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) // Light blue (#0ff) to
                                                    // green (#0f0)
        {
            mHueBarColors[index] = Color.rgb(0, 255, 255 - (int) i);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) // Green (#0f0) to yellow
                                                    // (#ff0)
        {
            mHueBarColors[index] = Color.rgb((int) i, 255, 0);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) // Yellow (#ff0) to red
                                                    // (#f00)
        {
            mHueBarColors[index] = Color.rgb(255, 255 - (int) i, 0);
            index++;
        }

        // Initializes the Paint that will draw the View
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        mPaint.setTextSize(12);
    }

    // Get the current selected color from the hue bar
    private int getCurrentMainColor() {
        int translatedHue = 255 - (int) (mCurrentHue * 255 / 360);
        int index = 0;
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) {
            if (index == translatedHue)
                return Color.rgb(255, 0, (int) i);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) {
            if (index == translatedHue)
                return Color.rgb(255 - (int) i, 0, 255);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) {
            if (index == translatedHue)
                return Color.rgb(0, (int) i, 255);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) {
            if (index == translatedHue)
                return Color.rgb(0, 255, 255 - (int) i);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) {
            if (index == translatedHue)
                return Color.rgb((int) i, 255, 0);
            index++;
        }
        for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) {
            if (index == translatedHue)
                return Color.rgb(255, 255 - (int) i, 0);
            index++;
        }
        return Color.RED;
    }

    // Update the main field colors depending on the current selected hue
    private void updateMainColors() {
        int mainColor = getCurrentMainColor();
        int index = 0;
        int[] topColors = new int[256];
        for (int y = 0; y < 256; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++) {
                if (y == 0) {
                    mMainColors[index] = Color.rgb(
                            255 - (255 - Color.red(mainColor)) * x / 255,
                            255 - (255 - Color.green(mainColor)) * x / 255,
                            255 - (255 - Color.blue(mainColor)) * x / 255);
                    topColors[x] = mMainColors[index];
                } else
                    mMainColors[index] = Color.rgb(
                            (255 - y) * Color.red(topColors[x]) / 255,
                            (255 - y) * Color.green(topColors[x]) / 255,
                            (255 - y) * Color.blue(topColors[x]) / 255);
                index++;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int translatedHue = 255 - (int) (mCurrentHue * 255 / 360);
        // Display all the colors of the hue bar with lines
        for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++) {
            // If this is not the current selected hue, display the actual
            // color
            if (translatedHue != x) {
                mPaint.setColor(mHueBarColors[x]);
                mPaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
            } else // else display a slightly larger black line
            {
                mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
            }
            canvas.drawLine(x + 10, 0, x + 10, 40, mPaint);
            // canvas.drawLine(0, x+10, 40, x+10, mPaint);
            //canvas.drawLine(x + width/27, 0, x + width/27,height/8 , mPaint);
        }

        // Display the main field colors using LinearGradient
        for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++) {
            int[] colors = new int[2];
            colors[0] = mMainColors[x];
            colors[1] = Color.BLACK;
            Shader shader = new LinearGradient(0, 50, 0, 306, colors, null,
                    Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);//0,50,0,306
            mPaint.setShader(shader);
            canvas.drawLine(x + 10, 50, x + 10, 306, mPaint);
            //canvas.drawLine(x + width/27, height/8 + 10, x + width/27, height*(5/6), mPaint);
        }
        mPaint.setShader(null);

        // Display the circle around the currently selected color in the
        // main field
        if (mCurrentX != 0 && mCurrentY != 0) {
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            canvas.drawCircle(mCurrentX, mCurrentY, 10, mPaint);
        }

        // Draw a 'button' with the currently selected color
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaint.setColor(mCurrentColor);
        //canvas.drawRect(10, 316, 138, 356, mPaint);
        //canvas.drawRect(width/27, height*(5/6), width/2, height, mPaint);

        // Set the text color according to the brightness of the color
        if (Color.red(mCurrentColor) + Color.green(mCurrentColor)
                + Color.blue(mCurrentColor) < 384)
            mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        else
            mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
       // canvas.drawText(
               // "New Color", 74,
                //340, mPaint);

        // Draw a 'button' with the default color
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaint.setColor(mDefaultColor);
        //canvas.drawRect(138, 316, 266, 356, mPaint);
        //canvas.drawRect(width/2, height*(5/6), width, height, mPaint);

        // Set the text color according to the brightness of the color
        if (Color.red(mDefaultColor) + Color.green(mDefaultColor)
                + Color.blue(mDefaultColor) < 384)
            mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        else
            mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        //canvas.drawText(
              //  "Default Color", 202, 340,
                //mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(276,366 );//276,366
        width = widthMeasureSpec;
        height = heightMeasureSpec;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            return true;
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        // If the touch event is located in the hue bar
        if (x > 10 && x < 266 && y > 0 && y < 40) {
            // Update the main field colors
            mCurrentHue = (255 - x) * 360 / 255;
            updateMainColors();

            // Update the current selected color
            int transX = mCurrentX - 10;
            int transY = mCurrentY - 60;
            int index = 256 * (transY - 1) + transX;
            if (index > 0 && index < mMainColors.length)
                mCurrentColor = mMainColors[256 * (transY - 1) + transX];

            // Force the redraw of the dialog
            invalidate();
        }

        // If the touch event is located in the main field
        if (x > 10 && x < 266 && y > 50 && y < 306) {
            mCurrentX = (int) x;
            mCurrentY = (int) y;
            int transX = mCurrentX - 10;
            int transY = mCurrentY - 60;
            int index = 256 * (transY - 1) + transX;
            if (index > 0 && index < mMainColors.length) {
                // Update the current color
                mCurrentColor = mMainColors[index];
                mListener.colorChanged("", mCurrentColor);
                // Force the redraw of the dialog
                invalidate();
            }
        }

        // If the touch event is located in the left button, notify the
        // listener with the current color
        //if (x > 10 && x < 138 && y > 316 && y < 356)
          //  mListener.colorChanged("", mCurrentColor);

        // If the touch event is located in the right button, notify the
        // listener with the default color
        //if (x > 138 && x < 266 && y > 316 && y < 356)
          //  mListener.colorChanged("", mDefaultColor);

        return true;
    }
}

public ColorPickerDialog(Context context, OnColorChangedListener listener,
        String key, int initialColor, int defaultColor) {
    super(context);

    mListener = listener;
    mKey = key;
    mInitialColor = initialColor;
    mDefaultColor = defaultColor;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    OnColorChangedListener l = new OnColorChangedListener() {
        public void colorChanged(String key, int color) {
            mListener.colorChanged(mKey, color);
            dismiss();
        }
    };

    setContentView(new ColorPickerView(getContext(), l, mInitialColor,
            mDefaultColor));
    setTitle("Pick Text Color");

    }
}
```

**Edit how to use in activity**

first make activity

```
implement OnColorChangedListener
```

then you get the callback function

```
@Override
    public void colorChanged(String key, int color) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        paint.setColor(color);
    }
```

and in your code you can make the dialog with the listener like this

```
ColorPickerDialog color = new ColorPickerDialog(this,this, "picker",Color.BLACK,Color.WHITE);
            color.show();
```

Comment: Is anyone paying attention to this thread anymore?  Because I found it, and I got the thing working.  The only trouble is that it doesn't scale well at all on high-rez devices.  Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: A small solution, but it uses a lot of "magic numbers" and it's not clear what it's doing with respect to scale of the hue bar.